# Train keras model in one and several threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing

I have a task to train a neural network (any neural network) in several threads and then compare the time of training with a one thread implementation. I have chosen to implement a simple perceptron using `keras` with `tensorflow` backend. From everything I've read so far about parallel training with `keras` I understood that it is indeed possible to specify the number of threads I want to use (for example, I have a computer with 4 logical processors, so I can train a neural network with 4 threads, then with 1 thread, and then compare the times). But I am a very beginner in `keras` and before I proceed with the task I just want ask the professionals and to make sure that what I want to do is really possible using this tool. I would also very much appreciate any links and literature that can help me with my task. Thanks in advance for any help